# Installing MongoDB 3.0 CentOS - Conflicts

Tags: mongodb, centos

Trying to install MongoDB 3 on Centos 6.6 - but keep getting the following error. I've tried the `yum makecache` solution that is outlined in some other posts. But to no avail.

I also, don't have any mongo install currently - this is a brand new CentOS box.

Full output below - no luck. Any ideas?

```
$ yum install mongodb-org-3.0.0
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.openitc.uk
 * extras: mirror.ukhost4u.com
 * updates: mirror.econdc.com
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mongodb-org.x86_64 0:3.0.0-2.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: mongodb-org-server = 3.0.0 for package: mongodb-org-3.0.0-2.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: mongodb-org-tools = 3.0.0 for package: mongodb-org-3.0.0-2.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: mongodb-org-mongos = 3.0.0 for package: mongodb-org-3.0.0-2.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: mongodb-org-shell = 3.0.0 for package: mongodb-org-3.0.0-2.el6.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mongodb-org-mongos.x86_64 0:3.0.0-2.el6 will be installed
---> Package mongodb-org-server.x86_64 0:3.0.0-2.el6 will be installed
---> Package mongodb-org-shell.x86_64 0:3.0.0-2.el6 will be installed
---> Package mongodb-org-tools.x86_64 0:3.0.0-2.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Conflict: mongodb-org-mongos-3.0.0-2.el6.x86_64 conflicts mongo-10gen-server
--> Processing Conflict: mongodb-org-mongos-3.0.0-2.el6.x86_64 conflicts mongo-10gen
--> Processing Conflict: mongodb-org-tools-3.0.0-2.el6.x86_64 conflicts mongo-10gen-server
--> Processing Conflict: mongodb-org-tools-3.0.0-2.el6.x86_64 conflicts mongo-10gen
--> Processing Conflict: mongodb-org-shell-3.0.0-2.el6.x86_64 conflicts mongo-10gen-server
--> Processing Conflict: mongodb-org-shell-3.0.0-2.el6.x86_64 conflicts mongo-10gen
--> Processing Conflict: mongodb-org-3.0.0-2.el6.x86_64 conflicts mongo-10gen-server
--> Processing Conflict: mongodb-org-server-3.0.0-2.el6.x86_64 conflicts mongo-10gen
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: mongodb-org-server conflicts with mongodb-org-3.0.0-2.el6.x86_64
Error: mongodb-org-shell conflicts with mongodb-org-3.0.0-2.el6.x86_64
Error: mongodb-org conflicts with mongodb-org-server-3.0.0-2.el6.x86_64
Error: mongodb-org-mongos conflicts with mongodb-org-server-3.0.0-2.el6.x86_64
Error: mongodb-org-tools conflicts with mongodb-org-server-3.0.0-2.el6.x86_64
Error: mongodb-org-shell conflicts with mongodb-org-server-3.0.0-2.el6.x86_64
Error: mongodb-org-mongos conflicts with mongodb-org-3.0.0-2.el6.x86_64
Error: mongodb-org-tools conflicts with mongodb-org-3.0.0-2.el6.x86_64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand exactly what happened, but I install Mongodb 3.0 on CentOS 7.
At first I did:

```
yum install -y mongodb-org --skip-Broken
```

Then re-run:

```
yum install -y mongodb-org
```

And after everything worked.

```
Installed:
mongodb-org.x86_64 0:3.0.0-3.el7

Dependency Installed:
  mongodb-org-mongos.x86_64 0:3.0.0-3.el7             mongodb-org-server.x86_64 0:3.0.0-3.el7
  mongodb-org-shell.x86_64 0:3.0.0-3.el7              mongodb-org-tools.x86_64 0:3.0.0-3.el7
```

Answer (score 0):

I chatted in the IRC, and it seems this is a known issue at the moment, that is currently in code review. The solution was to directly target the correct install ... using:

```
yum install -y mongodb-org-3.0.0-1.el6.x86_64 mongodb-org-mongos-3.0.0-1.el6.x86_64 mongodb-org-tools-3.0.0-1.el6.x86_64 mongodb-org-server-3.0.0-1.el6.x86_64 mongodb-org-shell-3.0.0-1.el6.x86_64 mongodb-org-tools-3.0.0-1.el6.x86_64
```